# How to sum values in a column based on other column(s) in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

| Geography | Sex | Year | Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | F | 2000 | 45320 |
| AB | M | 2000 | 42220 |
| ON | F | 2001 | 51230 |
| ON | M | 2001 | 51422 |

I want to sum the populations by province and year, where for example, I would get 46752 as the population of AB in the year 2000.

I have tried using `dplyr` and `summarise`, but keep getting stuck.

This is what I had so far:

```
count_province <- df %>% group_by(Geography, Year, Population) %>% summarise(
  prov_pop = sum(Population))
```

Comment: There are no rows in your example that has AB & 2001 in your table...

Comment: Sorry - I meant in 2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `group_by`, remove the `Population`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Geography, Year) %>%
   summarise(prov_pop = sum(as.numeric(Population), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: It gave me the following error:Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `prov_pop =
  sum(Population)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: Geography = "Alberta",
  Year = 2000.
Caused by error in `sum()`:
! invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: @bramos95 i assume you have a character class Population, so convert to numeric (`as.numeric`) in the update and it should work

Comment: @akron on my .csv I have it as Numbers, but tried as.numeric anyway. It gave me NA for some provinces, but the total for others, which is odd.

Comment: @bramos95.  If you check my code, i used `na.rm = TRUE`, in `sum`, so you shouldn't be getting NA as sum instead would be 0 if there are all NAs

Comment: @bramos95 there may be some characters (other than the digit) in the column that will result in NA when you convert with `as.numeric`.  You may need to check your csv file. or do `i1 <- is.na(as.numeric(df$Population)); df$Population[i1]` will give all those cases where you are getting NAs

Comment: @akron it entirely had to deal with my .csv file, and took a lot of tinkering to fix it and it finally worked! No need to fix for NA. Thank you for your solutions, much appreciated!!